# Fudge Dice Augmentation

Tags: fate, dice, homebrew

I'm looking into unique stunts that affect dice rolls in gameplay. Are there any rules or precedent on the use of more than 4 Fudge dice in rolls, or using a die to determine outcomes?

I'm thinking of stunts like these examples:

> **Desperation**: You may roll a 5th die during combat rolls as long as 3 or more stress boxes are filled.

> **Cruor Vitalis**: Heal a target ally for d6 shifts, but they must roll Will of the heal value or suffer mental stress.

**Are there actually any rules against using extra dice or using D6 in rolls, or is that up to the DM?**

Comment: An issue I see with "Desperation" is that the 5th die doesn't actually add any benefit; it could actually be a detrimental addition 33% of the time. Maybe if you added the 5th die, but ignored it if it were a -?

Comment: To add to @ProfessorCaprion, on average 1dF is 0. As far as I'm aware (coming from DFRPG), the power-level of stunts should be roughly equivalent to +2 on a roll in specialized circumstances. 0 is a lot lower than 2 in FATE.

Comment: I am aware of the negative effects on desperation there is another ability I have that actually augments it to ignore - rolls when empowered. my question is if there's actually any rules against using extra dice or using D6 enrolls or is that up to the DM

Comment: @Vert Well, FATE COREs rule mechanical system is more a toolbox that lets you adjust, adapt and create exactly the type of game that's just right for you, rather than a fixed set of rules. So any question about if something is against the rules in FATE is kind of moot. Generally, FATE questions come down to; can you do it (but not in the sense are you allowed), how to do it and is it a bad or good idea to do it?

Answer (score 4):

Unless you're talking about a specific implementation of Fate such as the Dresden Files RPG, the Fate ruleset doesn't *disallow* anything! If it's good for your game, they want you to do it, and questions of "is it against the rules" don't make sense in the context of Fate customisation.

That said, there is precedent for this: In the Atomic Robo RPG (which is a pretty new Fate RPG) Thomas Edison is an example NPC character on page 269. He has a stunt called

> THERE ARE NO RULES: Once per scene, when you invoke one of your aspects, instead of getting a bonus or a reroll, you may swap out a Fate die for a regular six-sided die--the kind that are numbered one through six.

Atomic Robo also provides examples of stunts which play with the way Fudge dice are read, such as this stunt of Tesla's (page 271):

> THE MAGNIFICENT THREE: When using a Science skill, if exactly three of your dice show the same result, you get a boost for free. For example, +++0 would get you a free boost, as would ---+ or 000-, but not ++++, ----, or 0000.